# javascript property of value type in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, value-type

My understanding is all objects of the same type will share the same prototype. So change to the prototype will reflect on every objects. But it seems not the case for property of value type. How is this kind of property stored?

```
function Person() {        
}

Person.prototype.name = "John";
var p1 = new Person();
p1.name = "Luke";
var p2 = new Person();
p2.name = "Mary";

console.log(p1.name);  // Luke instead of Mary
console.log(p2.name);  // Mary
```

In case I want to implement a object count of the same type. What's the best way to do it? In other OO language, you normally just use a static member to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype property access is **asymmetric**.

- **When you get a property** - if the object does not have it, it will fetch it from the prototype. This is [specified](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.2) as:

> 1. Let proto be the value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of O.
> 2. If proto is null, return undefined.
> 3. Return the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of proto with argument P.

- **When you set a property** - you *always* set it on the object and not the prototype. As specified [here](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2).

To illutstrate:

```
 var proto = {x:4};
 var child = Object.create(proto); // create object with prototype set to `proto`
 child.x; // 4, fetched from prototype
 child.x = 10;
 child.x; // 10, fetched from child
 proto.x; // 4, setting on child did not change the prototype
 Object.getPrototypeOf(child).x = 6; // you can get around it, and set on the proto.
```

You can read more about it, and why it works this way in [Steve Yegge's excellent "the universal design pattern"](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.co.il/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html#readwrite).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in case I want to implement a object count of the same type. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: @leon use a factory, creation of objects and managing a collection of objects is not the responsibility of an object itself. I'd create a PersonFactory object that holds a count of People, and create persons through it. That was a person is not in charge of things it does not need to be in charge of. (A static or global variable would also work, but is much worse). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I know the advantage of factory but I always like light-weight way to do things (less code). Thanks again.

Comment: One more question about your example, I'm not familiar with Object.create. I thought the object literal will only add own property. But your code suggests that the proto becomes the prototype of child object, which I didn't know. And what's constructor of child  and proto?

Comment: And when I debugging this code, the prototype of child is "Object" but proto.

Comment: @leon constructors are irrelevant here. In JavaScript objects inherit from objects. You can read more about `Object.create` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Thanks. But the prototype of child is "Object" instead of proto. Then the code you gave is not about modify the property of proto. Object.getPrototypeOf(child).x = 6 is actually accessing "object"

Comment: It's accessing `proto` - proto, is in turn an instance object. The prototype chain of `child` is `child -> proto -> Object.prototype`

Comment: I called console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(child)) after your code, and I got "[object Object]".

Answer (score 0):

When you try to retrieve a property, the object is interrogated to see if it has its own defined.  If it doesn't, its constructor's prototype is checked.  This happens all the way up the prototype chain until a value is found.

[prototype chain explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Here's an example.

```
// Person constructor.
var Person = function (name) {
    if (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
};

// method to print the name in the console
Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
}

// create two people with names
var person1 = new Person('Nicholas');
var person2 = new Person('Greg');

person1.sayName();
person2.sayName();

// =========================================
// This dude has no name.
var person3 = new Person();
person3.sayName();

// Add a name to the prototype.
// This name is available to all Person instances if they
// don't define their own.
Person.prototype.name = 'Dick';

// These two have their own names.
person1.sayName();
person2.sayName();  

// This guy doesn't have his own name, so he
// uses the one from the prototype.
person3.sayName();
```